# Какой правильно выбрать контроль доступа?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно выбрать систему доступа, если у меня есть ресурс, где может быть множество компаний с департаментами, у каждого департамента есть свой одинаковый функционал и мне нужно разделить каждый департамент так, что бы я видел только то что для моей компании и своего департамента, остального я не должен видеть.

Желательно с гибкой настройкой.

Нашел пример ABAC от CraftCamp/php-abac, но до конца я его не могу понять. Может кто поможет или научит как правильно сделать?
Благодарю.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, укажите что вы используете (фреймворк, cms или писали движок с нуля), также укажите будет ли пользователь авторизован.

Comment: Пользователь будет авторизован, написан собственный движок. Но рассматриваю переход на другой движок, где это реализовано.